# Is a question about configuring R to use a proxy server off-topic?

Tags: discussion, r

I'm trying to figure out how to configure R's proxy settings so I can download and install some packages. I know that stuff specific to R has been in the gray area for on-topic-ness in the past (and maybe it still is), so I want to know if this kind of question is on-topic enough for Cross Validated, or if I should instead take my chances asking it on Super User. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm one of those people who thinks that all R-focused questions should go to StackOverflow.  That is not the policy we decided on.

I think this would be most appropriate at StackOverflow.  It's not *purely* a programming question, but I can't imagine a question about CPAN (for example) getting turned away there.  There's tons of overlap between the StackOverflow R community and CV's, but I think the former is much more focused on R as software.

Better to ask it here than at SuperUser, though.  SO > CV > SU.

Comment: Until I read your answer, I would've guessed that if R had any following on Stack Overflow, it was a very small one. Thanks for sharing that helpful knowledge!

Comment: Speaking of Stack Overflow, I find your opinion—that my question would be most appropriate on SO—interesting. Considering my question is more about R as *software* than as a *programming language*, I'd think that it would belong more on Super User than Stack Overflow. So are you saying that, although it's not really on-topic at SO, its R community would ignore the off-topic-ness? Or are you saying that, of SO, CV, and SU, the question would be *most* on-topic at SO?

Comment: It's a balancing act between topicfulness and quality of responses.  It may indeed be most "on-topic" on SU, but who there is going to know anything about R?  Conversely, I think you'd get equally good responses here or on SO (likely from the same people), but I think this question is far more on-topic there than here.  In absolute terms, I think it is also sufficiently on-topic for SO.  Speaking as someone who's been watching the R tag since its inception, nobody's going to bat an eye over your question.

Comment: Okay, I've asked on Stack Overflow [(link)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4832560/594302). Thanks!

Comment: @Matt-parker I remember the many discussions we've had on CV about R questions ;) But I think that CV currently has the right balance of how it deals with R question. I agree that this question would be better in SO.